# Monitor broken despite ok device details

Tags: display, device-manager, monitor-settings

My laptop went through security and came out broken and yellow, and in some windows will be completely unrecognisable. 
I went to Device Management and the PnP Generic Monitor security details are "This device is working properly."

Is this because it's a physical issue e.g. damaged connected from the laptop to the monitor?

If possible, could you suggest what would cause this damage?

Flickering lines can be seen in other instances.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suspect physical damage, especially if there are any signs that "security" may have physically dismantled the laptop (e.g., unscrewed the case to look inside).

Answer (score 0):

The cause was found to be a loose motherboard - screen cable. This occuredcto dropping or manhandling the laptop. This was fixed personally accidentally after dropping the laptop.